# Is there an easier way of representing conditions in C++?

Tags: c++, language-features

I wrote a basic tic-tac-toe game based on multidimensional arrays. g[3][3]. In my program I have about 9 conditions like the one I am about to show you:

```
if((g[0][0] == X && g[0][1] == X && g[0][2] == X) || (g[0][0] == O && g[0][1] == O && g[0][2] == O))
```

This is quite insane. I am probably doing something wrong but this is why I am addressing this question. Is there an easier way of representing long and complicated conditions like this? For example couldn't I somehow do:

```
if(grid.hasXes)
```

Comment: A loop?  A lookup table?  A function?  Take your pick...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, can you give some examples of each?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably going about it the wrong way.  There are only 3^9, or
19683 possible combinations, so you can convert your grid to an `int`,
even on a 16 bit machine:

```
int
asInt( char const (&grid)[3][3] )
{
    int results = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i != 3; ++ i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j != 3; ++ j ) {
            results *= 3;
            switch ( grid[i][j] ) {
            case 'X':
                results += 1;
                break;

            case 'Y':
                results += 2;
                break;

            case ' ':
                break;

            default:
                assert(0);
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Afterwards, you can use the int to index into a table indicating who won
(if anyone).  Alternatively, you can convert just one or the other
player's position into a 9 bit int:

```
int
asInt( char const (&grid)[3][3], char who )
{
    int results = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i != 3; ++ i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j != 3; ++ j ) {
            results *= 2;
            if ( grid[i][j] == who ) {
                ++ results;
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

You can then use a simple linear search into a table, verifying that the
necessary bits are set:

```
static int const wins[] =
{
    0007, 0070, 0700,       //  rows
    0111, 0222, 0444,       //  columns
    0124, 0421              //  diagonals
};

class Wins
{
    int myToMatch;
public:
    Wins( char const (&grid)[3][3], char who )
        : myToMatch( asInt( grid, who ) )
    {
    }
    bool operator()( int entry ) const
    {
        return (entry & myToMatch) == entry;
    }
};
```

Then:

```
if ( std::find_if( begin( wins ), end( wins ), Wins( grid, 'X' ) )
            != end( wins ) {
    //  X wins
else if ( std::find_if( begin( wins ), end( wins ), Wins( grid, 'O' ) )
            != end( wins ) {
    //  O wins
else
    //  play another turn.
```

You could even consider keeping the grid as two `int`s, one per player.
The bit number for a position would be `3 * i + j`, and to test if a
move is legal:

```
bool
isLegal( int gridX, int gridY, int i, int j )
{
    return ((gridX | gridY) & (1 << (3 * i + j))) == 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow this answer pretty much makes me think my question was stupid since there are so many ways. This answer makes me feel so small, thanks!

Comment: @ThePlan Not at all.  Seeing such possibilities depends a lot on experience.  And the only way to get that experience, and to learn, is to ask such questions.  I thought it was a good question; that's why I put some effort into thinking up what I think is a good answer.  (And the bit bashing technique at the end is not something that's likely to occur to you unless you've actually done something similar in the past.)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest -- and most powerful -- way to deal with this kind of issue is simply by extracting the ugly code into  a function. That function can be a member of a class, if it's convenient, or simply a free function. In your case, the quick fix could be

```
bool hasXes(char[3][3] g) {
    return (g[0][0] == X && g[0][1] == X && g[0][2] == X) || (g[0][0] == O && g[0][1] == O && g[0][2] == O)
}
```

Then you can simply write:

```
if (hasXes(g)) ...
```

Comment: you should at least pass X to the function, or assume lambda availability. Or Boost.bind...

Answer (score 3):

now I got it...

```
bool check(char *g, int x, int y, int moveX, int moveY, char ch)
{
    for (int i(0); i<3; ++i)
    {
        if ((g+(y*3)+x) != ch) return false;
        x += moveX;
        y += moveY;
    }
    return true;
}
```

you use it like that:

```
if (check(g, 0, 0, 0, 1, 'O')) //checking O in the first row.
if (check(g, 0, 0, 0, 1, 'X')) //checking X in the first row.
if (check(g, 0, 0, 1, 0, 'O')) //checking O in the first column.
if (check(g, 0, 0, 1, 0, 'X')) //checking X in the first column.
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write functions to hide the complexity and enhance the readability of your main driver function.  For instance, you could check a row or column to see if it it's all equal to X or O.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
bool found = false;
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        if(g[i][j] == X)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found == true)
    {
        break;
    }
}
if(found == true)
{
    // do something because one of them had X.  i, j have the co-ordinates of the first find of it
}
else
{
    // none of them had X
}
```

There may be a way to use a goto as well, though those are heavily discouraged in c++.  If you only want a row at a time, only use 1 loop.

Comment: I have used gotos in my code despite the fact it's considered a bad practice because I had no patience to think for alternate loops.

Answer (score 0):

One more option to choose from. You can use memcmp if the storage is contiguous

```
if(!memcmp(g[0],"XXX",3) || !memcmp(g[0],"OOO",3))
```

Comment: Joke. I didn't vote at all. I gave you an imaginary +1 for cleverness and -1 for ugliness; they balance out to no vote.

Comment: That's fine for the rows.  Now how do you do the columns.  (And please: `memcmp` doesn't return a `bool`; don't pretend that it does.  It just confused people.)

Answer (score 0):

You could count the Xs or try to find them:

Assuming g is a 3 x 3 array, containing characters `X` or `O`:

```
char* end = g + 9;
std::count(g, end, 'X') > 0;
```

or more efficiently:

```
char* end = g + 9;
std::find(g, end, 'X') != end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this special case there is also the somewhat simpler comparison:

```
if(g[0][0] == g[0][1] && g[0][1] == g[0][2])
```

At least assuming there are only `X` and `O` possible. Otherwise this will become

```
if(g[0][0] == g[0][1] && g[0][1] == g[0][2] && ( g[0][1] == X || g[0][1] == O ) )
```

Which still is a lot simpler IMHO.

If you cannot simplify like this, use a loop as other have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Typesafe comments!

```
const bool first_is_xful = g[0][0] == X && g[0][1] == X && g[0][2] == X,
           second_is_xful = ...;

if (first_is_xful || second_is_xful || ...) ...
```

Or functions functions:

```
bool is_xful (int row, ...) ...

...

if (is_ixful(0) || ...
```